# center text in banner with out extra div

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I'd like to create a full width banner and combine it with flex's justify content and max-width to avoid using an extra div.
I'm not sure it's possible. But I'd like to try to avoid my first instinct of just adding a wrapper div and call it day. I feel there should be a better way.

```
<div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div class="banner-content">
      <p>read all our policies</p>
      <p><a href="">examine our license agreement</a></p>
    </div>
</div>



    .banner-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: black;

      .banner-content {
       //base
       color: white;     //not relevant
       font-size: 12px;  //not relevant

       //layout
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 1200px;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
       padding:9px 15px;  //not relevant
     }
   }
```

reference image : [text banner with full width background but max-width'ed text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqbM.png)

I'm using sass and what I'd like to do is

```
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
      <p>read all our policies</p>
      <p><a href="">examine our license agreement</a></p>
    </div>
```

I can't find a way of doing it with flex or grid. 
this lame pseudo-ish code is the direction I'm experimenting with:

```
.banner-wrapper {
 display: flex; 
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
 padding:9px auto;  //use padding similar to margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i ran your code in jsbin and the text is centered, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: wow. thank you.
I want to do the same thing the same thing, without the extra  "banner-wrapper" div.

full-width black background and  two text items space-between'd, with width 100% but max-width 1200px

Comment: possible guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276